# How to make Windows.Form-Element disappear when content is empty?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a SplitContainer that contains a textBox, which is used to inform about errors or speficic situations. But most of the handled cases don't produce errors and therefore the box is not needed. In thoses cases I would like to make it disappear. Setting `Visibile=false` is not what I intend, because it still limits the other Windows.Form-elements. Instead those elements should "grow" in the left space from the box.  Is there some thing like a floating disapear behaviour?

Comment: Does the text box in question fully occupy one of the split container panels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the text box in question is placed inside the let say right panel of the `SplitContainer` while the other controls - inside the left panel (I might be wrong, but otherwise I see no reason why you are mentioning the `SplitContainer` in the question). Then, depending on which panel of the `SplitContainer` contains the text box, you can set [Panel1Collaped](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.panel1collapsed(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Panel2Collapsed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.panel2collapsed(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `false` to make it disappear and let the other panel fully occupy the split container space.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the control to be removed, you can do:

```
textBox1.Dispose();
```

This also causes your other elements to "grow" in the left space like you wanted.